# simple form validation not working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Trying to loop through all the fields, and have the errors written above the form, autofocus, and background color changed to red ...

Form doesn't work.

Why?

Bonus points: would really also appreciate if you could explain how to name the fields individually in the `errorMessages` ...

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

        <script>

            function validateMe(){

                document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",validateForm); 

                function validateForm(){
                    //alert("Wheeeeee!");

                    var formy = document.getElementById("testy"); 

                    for (var i = 0; i < formy.length; i++) {
                        if (formy[i].value == "") {
                            document.getElementById("errorMessages").innerHTML = "Please don't leave blank"
                            document.form["testy"].focus();
                            formy[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
                            return false;
                        } 
                        else {
                            formy[i].style.backgroundColor = "#fff"
                        }
                        return true;
                    }


                }   

            }

            window.addEventListener("load",validateMe);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form name="" id="testy" action="" onsubmit="return validateMe">
                <p id="errorMessages"></p>
                First Name: <input type="input" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
                <br /><br />
                Last Name: <input type="input" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
                <br /><br />
                Email Address: <input type="input" name="email" id="email" />
                <br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Validate" id="button1" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Avoiding jQuery and HTML5 attributes validation since I'm trying to learn the nitty gritty of JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code with javascript validation. I would like to point out few things.
First you added return in the for loop so that will only check first element. Because either your condition is true or false it will always stops execution of it's next iteration and will get returned back.
Also you can use array for adding error messages with for different elements.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>

        <form name="" id="testy" action="" >
                <p id="errorMessages"></p>
                First Name: <input class='form-item' type="input" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
                <br /><br />
                Last Name: <input class='form-item' type="input" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
                <br /><br />
                Email Address: <input class='form-item' type="input" name="email" id="email" />
                <br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Validate" id="button1" />
        </form>

        <script>

    var form = document.getElementById("testy");

    form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var error = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
            if (form[i].value == "") {
                //document.getElementById("errorMessages").innerHTML += "Please don't leave blank<br/>";
                error.push("Please don't leave "+form[i].name+" blank<br/>");
                form[i].focus();
                form[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";                             
            } 
            else {
                form[i].style.backgroundColor = "#fff"
            }                        
        }
        if(error.length){
            document.getElementById("errorMessages").innerHTML = "<ul>";
            for(var i=0; i<error.length;i++){
                document.getElementById("errorMessages").innerHTML += "<li>"+error[i]+"</li>";
            }
            document.getElementById("errorMessages").innerHTML += "</ul>";
        }else{
            form.submit();
        }

    });

    var obj = document.getElementsByClassName("form-item");
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
        var item = obj[i];  
        item.onfocus = function(){
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
        }
    }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you! Do you mind if I ask a few questions to understand your answer?

Comment: Not at all. Please ask you questions.

Comment: is this line an anonymous function? `form.addEventListener("submit", function (e)` ?

Comment: why is this line needed ` e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: is there a way to remove the red background in the input boxes once a user is in it when trying to fix the blank space?

Comment: e.preventDefault is to stop the default behavior of an element. As I have used it for form so it will stop form submission we can use it for link click also so that link click don't redirect to other page. 
We needed preventDefault because we don't want to submit the form unless all form validations are checked.

Comment: if(error.length) is to check if there are any validation errors and if yes then it will print the error.

Comment: regarding removing red background. we can use onfocus but it will be outside of our validation function. So on focus of each field we can remove the red background.

Comment: should I make a separate question regarding removing the red background when a person is trying to fill in the blank?

Comment: You are welcome. Please check my updated code to see how to remove the red background on focus of field.

Comment: wow, thank you for taking the time to update the answer on how to remove the red background!

Comment: out of curiosity ... please excuse my naivete, but in order to remove the red background, you have to do a separate function outside of validation function? There's no way to do it within all in one function? Not asking you to write a new answer, just asking because I'm not sure what's possible in JS and what's not.

Comment: Yes, we need to write it outside of the validation function because the trigger for validation function to execute is when form is submitted. So if we write this code in that function it will only work when form will be submitted. And we don't want that. Correct?

Comment: also though, wondering how removal of red background function gets triggered? It's automatic when the focus is on the red background?

Comment: var obj = document.getElementsByClassName("form-item");
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
        var item = obj[i];  
        item.onfocus = function(){
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
        }
    }
This code is handling that. So it have nothing to do with redbackground. What I did is when ever the input field is in focus(clicked) , then change the background color to White(#fff).

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you so much for all your answers. I'm finally understanding bits and pieces of JS which formerly eluded me before. If I could upvote your answer several times more, I would. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your form validation;

HTML Form

```
<form name="" id="testy" action="">
        <p id="errorMessages"></p>
        First Name: <input type="input" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
        <br /><br />
        Last Name: <input type="input" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
        <br /><br />
        Email Address: <input type="input" name="email" id="email" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Validate" id="button1" />
</form>
```

JQuery Script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // When the browser is ready...
  jQuery(function($){

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#testy").validate({
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            first_name: { required: true },
            last_name: { required: true },

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            first_name: "Please enter your first name.",
            last_name: "Please enter your last name.",
            //txtPhone: "Please Enter your Phone No",
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email.",
                email: "Please enter valid email id"
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.formName();
        }
    });

  });

</script>
```

It is jQuery validation plugin for form validation. (https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond. I really appreciate it. I'm trying to actually learn JS, hence avoiding HTML5 attributes validation, and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",validateForm); No need of this line as in form you write onsubmit="return validateForm". Also onsubmit and onclick are different.

document.form["testy"].focus(); is generating an exception and your code does not reach till the statement "return false". Replace with document.getElementById("testy").elements[i].focus();
Also you can add some time delay.